# Flex: Display month name in DateField control

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, datefield

I'm using the MX DateField control in Flex and want to display the date as 01 Jul 2011 or 01 July 2011. Does anyone know how to do this? I tried setting the formatString to "DD MMM YYYY" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:DateFormatter id="myDf" formatString="DD MMM YYYY"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function formatDate(date:Date):String{
            return myDf.format(date);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:DateField id="dateField" labelFunction="formatDate" />
```

Found it in the LiveDocs at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_12.html

However this does not explain why the formatString property on the component does not work properly.
I can confirm that it does not work as expected.

Cheers

Comment: I think the reason is that MX DateField use its (less powerful) internal functions dateToString() and stringToDate() to parse and format values, instead of using the default formatters.

Comment: I think it's a result of a [long-standing Flex bug](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-25343); `dateToString()` and `stringToDate()` haven't been as fully-featured as the code used in `<mx:DateFormatter/>` elements. This bug also means you have to set `parseFunction()` to `null` when changing `labelFunction()` (see bug report).

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
<mx DateField id        = "dateField" 
              dayNames  ="["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"]"
              monthNames="["January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
                           "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
                           "November", "December"]" />
```

Since you mentioned 3 character month names, this is a good example.  If you don't need the day names, of course, remove that line.

```
<mx DateField id        = "dateField" 
              dayNames  ="["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"]"
              monthNames="["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May",
                           "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", 
                           "Nov", "Dec"]" 
           formatString = "DD MMM YYY" />
```

Hope this helps.